# How to substitute chars using unicode regex range

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, range

I am trying to remove chars from an unicode string. I have a whitelist of allowed unicode chars and I would like to remove everything that is not on the list.

```
    allowed_list = ur'[\u0041-\u005A]|[\u0061-\u007A]|[\u00C0-\u00D6]|[\u00D8-\u00F6]|[\u00F8-\u012F]|\u0131|[\u0386]|[\u0388-\u038A]'
    negated_list = ur'[^\u0041-\u005A]|[^\u0061-\u007A]|[^\u00C0-\u00D6]|[^\u00D8-\u00F6]|[^\u00F8-\u012F]|^\u0131|[^\u0386]|[^\u0388-\u038A]'
```

I am testing it with a subset of my list and I don't get why it is not working.

This removes all but lowercase latin chars:

```
    >>> mystr = 'Arugg^]T'
    >>> myre = re.compile(ur'[^\u0061-\u007A]', re.UNICODE)
    >>> result = myre.sub('', mystr)
    >>> result
    'rugg'
```

This removes all but uppercase latin chars:

```
    >>> mystr = 'Arugg^]T'
    >>> myre = re.compile(ur'[^\u0041-\u005A]', re.UNICODE)
    >>> result = myre.sub('', mystr)
    >>> result
    'AT'
```

But when I combine them, all chars get removed:

```
    >>> mystr = 'Arugg^]T'
    >>> myre = re.compile(ur'[^\u0041-\u005A]|[^\u0061-\u007A]', re.UNICODE)
    >>> result = myre.sub('', mystr)
    >>> result
    ''
```

When I tested the regex `[^\u0041-\u005A]|[^\u0061-\u007A]` on  https://pythex.org/ it does what I am expecting, but when I atempt to use it in my code, it is not doing what I want it to. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `A` is not in `a-z` so it gets removed. `a` is not in `A-Z` so it gets removed. For every single letter *one* of the sides of that `or` will match. You end up with nothing, logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicitly positive, regex class *items* are *OR*'d together.

Your regex is then the same as

`[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u012f\u0131\u0386\u0388-\u038a]`

---

But for the Negative regex class `[^]`, *items* are individually negated then *AND*'ed together.

That regex is then

`[^\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u012f\u0131\u0386\u0388-\u038a]`

which is logically the same as

`[^\u0041-\u005A]` and `[^\u0061-\u007A]` and `[^\u00C0-\u00D6]` and `[^\u00D8-\u00F6]` and `[^\u00F8-\u012F]` and `[^\u0131]` and `[^\u0386]` and `[^\u0388-\u038A]`

---

What you tried to do was negate each item, then *OR* them together
which is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not correct, you are using `|` which checks if either one is true.

You need to create one expression with multiple ranges,

`[^\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A]` will match any characters except range `\u0041-\u005A` or `\u0061-\u007A`.

```
import re

regex = r"[^\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A]"

test_str = "Arugg^]T"

myre = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
result = myre.sub('', test_str)
print(result)

# output,
AruggT
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing all characters that are

not in `'[^\u0041-\u005A]'` **or** not in `[^\u0061-\u007A]'` (due to the `^`) .

If either one is true, all get replaced by '' - so its always true no matter what you have.

Use `ur'[^\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A]'` instead (both ranges inside one [...].